# Why does my output file contain mysterious extra columns filled with the variables of my dataset?

Tags: sas, ascii

This is really strange, but I'm hoping you can help. I'm using the FILE statement in a DATA step in SAS 9.3 to import someone else's SPSS file, so that I can recode and create some variables, and then output a file. I wasn't having luck with INFILE, so I used PROC IMPORT and then translated the data into a txt format.

```
proc import datafile = 'C:\file.sav'
    out = work.master_A
    dbms = sav
    replace;
run;

data work.master_B;
    file 'C:\file.txt'
        delimiter = '09'x
        dsd
        dropover
        lrecl = 32767;

    put
        'animal' '09'x
        'vegetable' '09'x
        'mineral' '09'x

    set  work.master_A;

        format animal $11.;
        format vegetable $10.;
        format mineral $8.;

        put animal @;
        put vegetable $ @;
        put mineral @;

run;
```

I know this should be a really simple task. But, no matter what type of output file I specify (.txt, .csv), the output file contains additional columns. These columns don't have variable names/headers. The column cells, though, are populated with the names of the data columns.

For example, if my original data is:
animal  vegetable   mineral
cat     broccoli    quartz
dog     asparagus   diamond
bird    ficus       shale

the output data is:
animal  vegetable   mineral
cat     broccoli    quartz  animal  plant   mineral animal  plant   mineral
dog     asparagus   diamond animal  plant   mineral animal  plant   mineral
bird    ficus       shale   animal  plant   mineral animal  plant   mineral

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Your first PUT statement is missing a semi-colon?  Was that a typo here or did your actual program not have an end to that PUT statement?

Comment: Does the PROC IMPORT really have anything to do with the question?  It sounds like you just want to know how to output a dataset to a CSV file.

Answer (score 1):

Your IMPORT step looks fine. You haven't shown any attempt at transforming any variables so let's assume you did that properly.

The problem you describe sounds like it is caused by re-writing the header for every observation of the input dataset.  You need to restrict it to only write the header on the first iteration of the data step.

```
data _null_;
  file 'C:\file.txt' dsd dlm='09'x;
  if _n_=1 then put
    'animal' '09'x
    'vegetable' '09'x
    'mineral' 
  ;
  set master_A;
  put animal vegetable mineral;
run;
```

You could just use PROC EXPORT to write a delimited file.

```
proc export data=master_A outfile='c:\file.txt' dbms=dlm;
  delimiter='09'x;
run;
```

If you want to limit it to just those three columns you can just use the KEEP= dataset option.

```
proc export data=master_A(keep=animal vegetable mineral) outfile='c:\file.txt' dbms=dlm;
  delimiter='09'x;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks, Tom! Yes, thankfully the missing semi-colon was just a typo here. Good catch! And, yes! That's exactly what it's doing! Any idea why? I've never run into this before, and it's driving me absolutely nuts that I don't understand what's going on. PROC EXPORT is a great idea, except that I really need to specify the formatting for each variable. So, I suppose I could go with the first of your three options above, adding in the syntax to specify formats? Thanks for your help and any additional insights!!! You're awesome!

Comment: The `IF _N_=1` test will make it output the header line only for the first pass through the data step. Not sure what you mean about formatting. A CSV file does not have formatting. Perhaps you do not want a delimited file at all? Normally I remove any formats attached to character variables. You might want to attach formats to DATE variables. You can use `format _character_;` to remove them from character or use `_all_` to remove then all. You can then add back formats for DATES and things that need them. I find using YYMMDD10. for dates makes them much more portable.

Comment: Oh my gosh! Thanks, Tom! I don't know why I was having a brain freeze and trying to assign formats to an unformatted file type! I just need to apply formats to the exported xlsx file. Duh! Any thoughts as to why it's re-writing the header for every observation of the input dataset? I've never run into that before. Thanks a million!

Comment: If you run the code I posted it will not write the header more than once. In the SAS data step it will automatically increment the variable `_N_` fro each pass through the data step. So in this simple program it is the same and an observation counter. By placing the lines that write the header inside of a `if _n_=1 then ....` conditional it will only write the header once.

Comment: Thanks, Tom! You're right! I'm just curious as to why it seemingly randomly started doing that. So strange. Thanks for the workaround!